# HMVC and Template library (by Phil Sturgeon) in Codeigniter

Tags: templates, codeigniter, hmvc

I am using [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) and [Template library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/codeigniter-template) (by Phil Sturgeon). The problem occur when I use `Modules::run` in my code:

```
$this->template->title("Some title")->set_partial('header', 'showmessage')->build('showanothermessage', $data);
```

and in showmessage.php partial view:

```
echo Modules::run("goodbye");
```

The error page appear with:

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: GoodBye::$agent
>
> Filename: libraries/template.php
>
> Line Number: 122
>
> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function is_mobile() on
>   a non-object in
>   D:\Binh\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\libraries\template.php on
>   line 122

How to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
My `goodbye` controller:

```
class GoodBye extends MY_Controller{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function Index(){ echo "Goodbye"; }
}
```

My `MY_Controller`:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // default layout
        $this->template->set_layout("home_layout");
    }
}
```

My `autoload` file:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','template');
$autoload['helper'] = array();
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

Comment: Can we see the `goodbye` controller please, any base controllers your are extending with it, and your `autoload.php`? This suggests that the user agent library is not loaded in the `goodbye` controller since `modules::run()` runs independently from the current controller.

Comment: I've removed `parent::__construct();` from `GoodBye` controller and it works. Can you explain why?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't got a clue. What does `application\libraries\template.php line 122` say?

Comment: It said that: `$this->_is_mobile = $this->_ci->agent->is_mobile();`

Comment: The only thing it can mean is that `Template::_ci` isn't an object, but how that would happen I can only guess. What exact version of the template library are you using?

Comment: Template Library 1.9.0 http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show

Comment: I've removed parent::__construct(); from GoodBye controller and it works. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my MY_Controller to:

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // default layout
        $this->template->set_layout("home_layout");
    }
}
```

It worked!

Comment: Ohhhh I totally missed that! Yeah you have to extend `MX_Controller` to use wiredesignz's HMVC and take advantage of the extended Loader class, Lang, etc. This is actually right in the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home): *"To use HMVC functionality, such as Modules::run(), controllers must extend the MX_Controller class."*